# VP8 won’t run under IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, jwplayer, vp8

I want to stream a video by using HTML5 and the VP8 codec.
It’s working fine on Chrome, but I can’t run it in IE. It will return an “invalid resource” error. I installed a VP8 codec and restarted the machine.

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" >
    <source id="srcWebm" src="http://www.urlfooo.org/test/video.WebM" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8,vorbis"'/>
</video>
```

I tried to remove the codec information, but it didn’t work. I tried to run the video by passing it to jw-player and that also didn’t work. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried installing https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf ? IE doesn't support WebM out of the box. Just installing a VP8 codec won't work as it needs to support the webm container format too.

Comment: Yeah, IE9 and IE10 only work with MP4 out of the box.